# Emergency mode erased all my files

Tags: home-directory, recovery-mode

Sometimes it happens that after an update my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS reboots in emergency mode. First time I ran `fsck /dev/sda1` and solved the problem with no bad consequences. But second time it happened, running the same command, sure I could boot regularly and login to my account, but all my files and settings seem to be gone: no more documents, no more pictures, etc.
I have two disks, an SSD with the filesystem and the hard disk with my home folder.
All my previously installed programs are still there though, so I guess my SSD hasn't been touched, only my hard disk.
Anyway, does this mean I lost everything forever? Is there a way I can recover my files?

Thank you!
Olly

Comment: Take a look at https://www.fosslinux.com/41727/the-6-best-linux-file-recovery-software.htm and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/top-best-linux-data-recovery-tools. Those were the first 2 links to pop up when googling your question. Back things up on another drive than the HDD.

Comment: Are you sure the files were erased? Could it be just that the hard disk is no longer being mounted on your home folder mount point?

Comment: The first thing to do - before attempting any file recovery software - is to boot into a live usb session, then mount your drives and see if your data is there. If it is, take the opportunity to back it all up to external media and then attempt repair. Whether or not you retrieve your files - and I sincerely hope you do - use this as a warning that you *must* always have backups of important data. Good luck!

Comment: It's very unlikely that any update spawned file system corruption that forced a `fsck`. It's unbelievably unlikely it happened more times from different updates.  What *does* cause file system corruption are things like power problems , improper forced shutdowns, failing cables, or a failing hard drive.

Comment: Thank you all guys, yeah my original home folder must be still there, because Disk usage shows Occupied: 105GB, those must be all my files!! But now I'm stuck again: I can launch ubuntu via live usb, but gparted shows only /dev/sda1 with my "new" home folder and no traces of other home folders.. what should I do now?